# Any train planner website in the UK without giving destination?

Tags: uk, trains

Is there any train travel planner website in the UK that shows possible destinations from a point? Something Like Google flight explorer.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a list of practically all the railway stations in the country?

Comment: You might be interested in this Q&A https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103761/any-railway-stations-more-than-1-change-from-london

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any ideal solutions but there are various ways to get a list of all trains leaving from a station that day. For example [here](https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/search/detailed/gb-nr:DON/2021-05-28/0000-2359?stp=WVS&show=pax-calls&order=wtt) is a list of all trains departing from Doncaster today. Which gives a clear (if long) list of possible final destinations.